# Construction of an explicit homotopy equivalence between pairs of topological space

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Suppose $H$ denote the southern hemisphere in $S^n$ and $p$ denotes the south pole. An exercise from Weintraub's book on Algebraic Topology (Exercise 1.3.2) asks us to prove that the inclusion between the pairs $(S^n,p) \to (S^n,H)$ is a homotopy equivalence of pairs.

I can see it through pictures, however I am unable to write it down rigorously. I am not very much well equipped with polar coordinates etc. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: First thing to try would be to write down a homotopy for $n=2$, because there one can easily visualize a stereographic projection.

Comment: Hint: take the (identity, inclusion) map $(S^n, p) \to (S^n, H)$ and in the other direction, a map which exactly crushes $H$ to $p$. Under the stereographic projection from the north pole, this could be something like $(r, \vec v) \mapsto (\max(r-1, 0), v)$.